# Find most frequently used tables and fields in DB2

Tags: db2, database-administration

Is there any query to find the most frequent accessed table and fields in DB2 (AS400). I need this information to cache some data in order to improve the performance of our systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check view qsys2.SYSTABLESTAT for table access details (logical_reads, physical_reads,etc..). Not sure about field level access details.